# Numpy - How can I transform this array without using python loops?

Tags: python, numpy

My input is a list of y_true labels, where the element in position `i` contains a value in the range of `0..len(classes)` and depicts what class that element of the data set truly is. `i` ranges from `0` to `len(data)`.  Example below:

```py
# 5 elements in data, 3 classes, all of which had representation in the data:
y_true = [0,2,1,0,1]
```

I want my output to be a list of lists that is`len(data)` by `len(classes)`, where inner list `i` would have a `1` in the position of y_true[i], and `0` in the other `len(classes)-1` slots, example:

```py
#same configuration as the previous example
y_true = [0,2,1,0,1]  
result = [[1,0,0],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]
```

Here's how I'm initilazing `result`:

```py
result = np.zeros((len(y_true), max(y_true)+1))
```

However I haven't been able to make any further progress with this issue. I tried using `add.at(result, y_true, 1)` and this with y_true's shape flipped, but neither produced the result I wanted. What fuction(s) can achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Edit: For better clarity on what I want to achieve, I made it using a for loop:

```py
result = np.zeros((len(y_true), max(y_true)+1))
for x in range(4):
  result[x][y_true[x]] = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fancy indexing:

```
result = np.zeros((len(y_true), max(y_true)+1), dtype=int)
result[np.arange(len(y_true)), y_true] = 1
```

output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

##### alternative

an interesting alternative might be to use [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.get_dummies(y_true).to_numpy()
```

output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```